# AD Connect Wizard doesnt accept my Azure AD Global Admin Credentials

Tags: azure

Im trying to connect my onprem AD to my Azure AD using the AD connect wizard but Im stuck in the part where I enter the credentials of my Global Administrator account that I have in Azure, Ive done some research and Im unable to find any answers specific to this issue.. very odd, some have recommended me to change the policy of the password for this account to never expire but that doesnt make sense for me because its a brand new account that I just created..

Any help is greatly appreciated as Im trying to practice with Azure (:

[Unable to Connect to Azure AD with my Global Admin credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ29u.jpg)

Comment: Try logging in to e.g. portal.azure.com with the global admin user, does that work?

Comment: That does not work, it tells me that the user account doesnt exist.

Comment: You need to double-check your username and password then.

Comment: Thanks man, sry for my late reply, I will try to change the policy of the password for the Global Administrator account so that it doesn't expire and see how that goes.

Someone said to me that what I have to do first before I even try to use AD connect is to establish a trust between my onprem network and an Azure Vnet? Is this true? odd.. because when I read about the process of how to configure AD connect it didnt mention any of that on the prerequisites of the guide.

Many thanks!

Comment: No that is not needed.

Comment: Oh ok great, I wanted to know that!! Thanks so much Juunas!!

Comment: I missed the part that after I create the Global Admin account I have to logon to the portal at least once so that it promts me to change the password and after I did that it then took the Global Admin credentials just fine on the ADConnect wizard, thanks for your help Juunas!!

Comment: No problem :) Yeah that is a standard feature, if you reset passwords/create new users, you always get a temporary password that must be changed. Logging in to Azure portal is usually the easiest way to assign the new password.

Comment: Got it! thanks again ( :